# How to upgrade Postgres93.app

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I have Postgres93.app installed (version 9.3.1), and cannot enable or run PLPython, presumably because of this: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/150.

How do I upgrade to the latest PostgresXX.app version and preserve my existing data?  Is this as simple as just installing the new app version, or do I need to do a backup and restore, move/upgrade data files, etc, for the databases I wish to preserve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I received a reply via Twitter that I simply need to install the updated app.  I'll post if that does not go smoothly.

Comment: Everything appears to be working OK after the upgrade, including being able to enable PLPython.  Some notes:

Comment: 1. The Postgres app is now called "Postgres.app", whereas the previous one was "Postgres93.app".  
2. It appears the data is still located under the old app.  I think I'll leave well enough alone, keep both apps, and remember to run the right one.